# How can I remove the Lubuntu packages after installing ubuntu-desktop on top of Lubuntu?

Tags: package-management

On this machine, I installed Lubuntu 12.04 and then installed the `ubuntu-desktop` package. Now there is some Lubuntu software, such as the Lubuntu Software Center, Xscreensaver, and Abiword, that needs to be removed.

There are plenty of scripts online, like [this one](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-completely-uninstall-remove-lubuntu-desktop), that describe how to get back to a pure Ubuntu desktop (after installing the `lubuntu-desktop` package) by removing all the Lubuntu packages, that is, the packages that `lubuntu-desktop` depends on. Can I use that script to remove the old Lubuntu packages and fully migrate to pure Ubuntu? I am worried that the script may remove some packages, like `libbluray`, that Ubuntu needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the removal as pointed in the link you provided but afterwards I suggest you to perform:

> sudo apt-get -f install

should signal and try to resolve any problem it finds relative to installed packages.

Still I don't like such approaches as I'm not sure Lubuntu uses the same repositories as Ubuntu.

Complementing:
Do a

> dpkg --get-selections > ~/Desktop/ubuntu_packages

into a ubuntu machine this will give you a list of packages on a ubuntu machine. Do the same for your lubuntu.

> dpkg --get-selections > ~/Desktop/lubuntu_packages

Do a diff, remove the packages present only in lubuntu. Then

> cat ~/Desktop/ubuntu_packages > sudo dpkg --set-selections && sudo apt-get
>   dselect upgrade

To install only the packages needed for ubuntu

Comment: A point of information: Lubuntu does, in fact. use the same software repositories as Ubuntu does. This seems like the answer to a different question... That command will resolve any problems with uninstalled dependencies, but if there is software I don't want, whether its dependencies are installed correctly or not, I will still be in the same pickle.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by running the script on the website, and then reinstalling the `ubuntu-desktop` package. I have a feeling that there are some software packages that are left over somehow, so maybe vfbsilva's answer is more reasonable.